# Sequelize Instance method save() concurrency behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

This might be a bit of a silly question but if I have 2 API endpoints and a basic Sequelize model like so:

```
var User = storage.database.define('user', {
  email: {
    type: sql.STRING,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true,
    },
  },
  data: sql.JSON,
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: true,
  hooks: {
    beforeUpdate: user => {
      user.set('data', user.data)
    },
  },
})

function getUser(email) {
  return User.findOne({
    where: { email },
  }).then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      throw {error: 'Unknown User'}
    }
    return user
  })
}

api.get('/one/:email', function(req, res, next) {
   getUser(req.params.email)
      .then(user => {
         user.data.someField = 1234;
         setTimeout(() => {
            user.save()
         }, 1000)
         res.send('one')
      })
})

api.get('/two/:email', function(req, res, next) {
   getUser(req.params.email)
      .then(user => {
         // update a different data field and/or the same field as in `one`
         user.data = { otherField: 'updated it', someField: 9999 };
         user.save()
         res.send('two')
      })
})
```

What happens if the same user sends 2 requests (one to each)? Will one override the other? If so, what happens if in `two` I don't set `someField` and instead just change the `otherField` and save it. Will the data set in `one` be lost?

If data is overridden, what is the recommended way to work with Sequelize Instances and update fields such as `data` without overriding data sent in other requests?

Comment: I guess this depends on how the database handles changes to JSON data, but I think it would be relatively easy to test yourself (or check and see which queries Sequelize runs for each type of update).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are overriding the whole data field in the route `two`, `someField` will be lost.

As I know `instance.set()` supports nested field updates through dot-syntax, you should use that in this way:

```
user.set('data.otherField', 'updated it');
user.save()
```